# 2SUM variant with 2 arrays

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out. I think I came up with a solution but its not elegant at all, I was wondering if any of yall could think of anything else. This is the problem

```
In the 2-Way-2- Sum decision problem, we are given arrays A and B of length
n containing (not necessarily distinct) integers, and we must determine whether there are
two pairs of indices i1, j1, i2, j2 ∈ {1, 2, . . . , n}, i1 ̸ = i2, j1 ̸ = j2 for which
A[i1] + A[i2] = B[j1] + B[j2].
Design an efficient algorithm that solves the 2-Way-2- Sum problem and has time com-
plexity O(n2 log n) in the setting where operations on individual integers take constant
time.
```

The approach I came up with is to initially sort the arrays, then iterate possible sums of one of the arrays and store it. Then I can iterate through the second array checking if any of the sums are present in the other taking n^2log n time because im searching the sum array using binary search inside two for loops. However is there a more efficient and elegant approach that doesnt require seperate memory use. I was thinking of something like this but im not sure if it makes sense

```
void solve(int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2){
    if(i1 >= i2 || j1 >= j2)
        return false;
    si = A[i1] + A[i2];
    sj = B[j1] + B[j2];
    if(si == sj)
        return true;
    else if(sj < si){
        solve(i1, i2 - 1, j1, j2);
        solve(i1, i2, j1 + 1, j2);
    }
    else{
        solve(i1+1, i2, j1, j2);
        solve(i1, i2, j1, j2 - 1);
    }
}
```

Does the code above make sense to anyone else? Thanks.

Comment: One approach to solving the problem with the desired complexity is to first compute all sums of pairs of elements in arrays $A$ and $B$ and store the sums of array $A$ in an array of sums and the sums of array $B$ in a separate array. Then use binary search given a sum of array $A$ to find whether the desired sum array of $B$ is present. This results in a time complexity of $O(n^2 \lg n)$.

Comment: The recursive solution you proposed has an exponential time complexity. It may be improved by using dynamic programming, but even in this case the time complexity would reduce to $O(n^4)$ since there are that many subproblems. By the way in your recursive solution you specified the return type to be void, yet you return some data in your function definition.